# Selecting the closest element with a matching data attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create buttons that have data attributes storing their ID. When clicked, I want to find some information on the button that was clicked and display a relevant modal with information. The issue is the client is using a page builder and the HTML has extra code in it than what I am writing. So when clicking the buttons, you are not actually clicking the intended element that contains the attribute. Is there a way to select the closest element that has the data attribute data-idschool?

for example:

```
<div data-idschool="1">
 <button>I am being clicked!</button>
</div>
```

Here is my JS in which I find the information tied to that data attribute ID in my JSON to pull information that is currently not working:

```
const popUpInfo = schoolInfo.find(
        (x) => x.id == school.closest(dataset.idschool)
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selector string `[data-idschool]` to get to the element, then get its dataset:

```js
const schoolInfo = [
  { id: '1' }
];

const school = document.querySelector('button');
const popUpInfo = schoolInfo.find(
  (x) => x.id == school.closest('[data-idschool]').dataset.idschool
);
console.log(popUpInfo);
```

```html
<div data-idschool="1">
  <button>I am being clicked!</button>
</div>
```